Can I change/update/modify the process templates on a Azure DevOps Server?
Sometime ago, I have restored a TFS db on a SQL Server, and after installing the ADO Server locally, I have attached the db as a collection to the ADO server. I have done that using the ADO Server management console's wizard. I have no issues accessing the collection from the browser.
Now, I would like use the DataMigration Tool to move the ADO Service. However, when I run the 'Migrator.exe validate /collection:http/localhost/ /connectionString: /region: /tenantdomainname:' command, I get the following error

[Error] Project Process Validation Failed

I can't share the entire log, but there are lots of error lines almost identical to this one

ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\LinkTypes\ABC.LinkTypes.Cloned.xml:2: TF402583: Custom link type ABC.LinkTypes.Cloned is invalid because custom link types aren't supported.

During the restoring of the db, or the initial setup of the ADO Server (can't really remember), I had some warnings about the process template, that it's outdated and might cause failure down the line. And I had to tick a checkbox, to confirm i understand the risk (I didn't). Now, when I try to "repair" the installation of the ADO server, I cannot get that checkbox back.
Does anyone know how can I change the process templates? Any help is appreciated.
I have tried reinstalling the ADO Server; detaching/re-attaching of the collections

When looking through the logs, I can see that in some projects, there is this line

[Info   @10:59:08.582] Step : ProcessValidation INFO - Custom process added a link type 'ABC.LinkTypes.Cloned'.

But when I export the processes from ADO,  none of them have this LinkedType. Where can I find out why, and how is it adding those?

Azure DevOps Services does not support custom link types. So, you need to remove the custom link types from all XML files of the process templates before migration:

Download the process template from your Azure DevOps Server.

Remove the custom link types from all XML files of the process templates.

Upload the updated process template back to your Azure DevOps Server.

Try the validation again.


Related documentations:

Resolve validation errors
Upload or download a process template
Customize a process template



I have downloaded the processes templates from the ADO Server, but there isn't any ABC.LinkTypes.Cloned.xml file, or even linktype in the LinkedType directory. The only linkedtypes in the processes templates are Affects, SharedStep, TestedBy and SharedParameterLink. It seems these are valid, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/import-process/resolve-errors?view=azure-devops#tf402583-custom-link-type-name-is-invalid-because-custom-link-types-arent-supported

@voodoo-cowboy, Search and check all the xml files in the processes template.

I can't find any other LinkedTypes in any of the files.

@voodoo-cowboy, The custom link type reported in the error message is ABC.LinkTypes.Cloned, did you search for it in all the XML files? If you also have other custom processes templates in your Azure DevOps Server collection, you also need to check them.

I have downloaded all the process templates and searched through all of them. The only linktypes i can find in there are those 4 types i mentioned earlier. I have no clue where these ABC.LinkTypes.Cloned types are even coming from.. I mean, the ABC part is correct, since it's the name of the collection, but that's about it.

Looking through the logs again, I can see this message

[Info   @10:59:08.582] Step : ProcessValidation INFO - Custom process added a link type 'ABC.LinkTypes.Cloned'.

How can i disable the addition of those links? Is there some flags/options I can feed into the command?

@voodoo-cowboy, No available flags/options on the "Migrator.exe validate" command. Di you try to search for the keyword "Cloned" from all the XML files of the process templates?

I've tried searching for "Cloned" in all of the XMLs, but I only get ABC.Cloned as a refname in different  elements throughout different WITD XMLs, f.ex.











@voodoo-cowboy, Try to clean the lines that are referencing "ABC.Cloned", or remove "ABC.Cloned" related object from the lines.

Tried that - same result. When looking through the logs, I can see that those types are added during the validate, I can see that these elements were added in some Custom processes. Managed to delete the custom link types using the witadmin tool

There are limitations in ADO Service, that doesn't support the migration of custom linked types. Therefore, moving those wasn't really an option, so their removal was the solution. Using the witadmin tool's deletelinktype solved it.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
